# How many FPGA can be attached to one computer?

Tags: fpga, mining-setup

I am looking at this. Dual FPGA X6500 Mining Card Rev 3 (Without Heatsinks)

So we connect the card via USB and the card will mine?

Should I buy one FPGA or several ones? Where do I attach the FPGA? PCI? USB?

Comment: I think ~$600 for 400MH/s is not the best deal. Myself, I'm waiting for these to show up (although it's not sure if they are real or just nonsense), they offer 3.5GH/s for $149: http://news.yahoo.com/butterfly-labs-announces-next-generation-asic-lineup-054626776.html

Comment: 100% nonsense. BFL have a very bad reputation for never shipping products on time and over-estimating performance. It also makes no financial sense why they would price the product that cheaply.

Comment: I don't think you should ask "how many should I buy" questions on SE. Please review your question to be non-personal and objective. You branch a bit too much from the title of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I know, you can connect basically any amount of FPGA cards to one computer through USB hubs. Case in point:

[image]

Comment: how much money those monster make?

Comment: An operating system may have limits.  With USB, a driver may be needed to address devices beyond nine.    Some hardware requires (or benefits from ) drivers too.

Comment: I feel sorry for that lone desk fan.